# Trouble linking parallel array and combo box

Tags: c#

I'm working on a class assignment and I'm trying to learn how to link my parallel arrays to a combo box selection. My textbook doesn't have the information I need and I was hoping someone here could help. My assignment is to build a Payroll System that displays the net pay after taxes. I'm trying to set it up so that a user selects an employee from the combo box and presses a button to calculate the net pay and display the results as well as other employee info that you might see on a paycheck. When I run the program and press the calculate button after making my selection nothing happens. Can anyone tell me why its not working?

[Picture of what the user interface looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztB1q.png)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ZNSPayrollSystem
{
    public partial class ZNSPayrollSystem : Form
    {

        public ZNSPayrollSystem()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            string[] arr = { "001 Peters", "002 Barnes", "003 Harris" };
            cboEmp.DataSource = arr.ToArray();


        }

        private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //parallel arrays            
            int[] empID = { 001, 002, 003 };
            string[] empName = { "James Peters", "Sarah Barnes", "Jessica Harris" };
            double[] hrsWorked = { 40, 30, 45 };
            double[] empWage = { 55.50, 65.50, 75.70 };

            //declarations          
            double dblTaxRate = 8.2 / 100;
            double dblNetPay;
            double dblGrossPay;
            double dblTaxWithheld;
            int i = cboEmp.SelectedIndex;

            dblGrossPay = hrsWorked[i] * empWage[i];
            dblTaxWithheld = dblGrossPay * dblTaxRate;
            dblNetPay = dblGrossPay - dblTaxWithheld;

            txtEmpID.Text = empID[i].ToString();
            txtEmpName.Text = empName[i];
            txtHrsWork.Text = hrsWorked[i].ToString();
            txtWage.Text = empWage[i].ToString();
            txtGross.Text = dblGrossPay.ToString();
            txtTax.Text = dblTaxWithheld.ToString();
            txtNetPay.Text = dblNetPay.ToString();

        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtEmpID.Text = "";
            txtEmpName.Text = "";
            txtHrsWork.Text = "";
            txtWage.Text = "";
            txtGross.Text = "";
            txtTax.Text = "";
            txtNetPay.Text = "";
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Make sure the button is actually **wired up** to that event handler.

Comment: @TriV no, there is no error message. It's just nothing happens when I press the Calculate button.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Sorry I know this a newbie question but can you tell me how to "wire up" the button to the event handler?

Comment: Click on the Button.  Then in the **Properties Pane** (bottom right of the screen by default), click on the "Lightning Bolt" Icon to see the Events.  Scroll down and find the Click entry and make sure it has "btnCalc_Click" in there.

Comment: @Idle_Mind That was it!!! I can't believe it was that simple!?! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Click on the Button. Then in the Properties Pane (bottom right of the
>   screen by default), click on the "Lightning Bolt" Icon to see the
>   Events. Scroll down and find the Click entry and make sure it has
>   "btnCalc_Click" in there. – Idle_Mind
>
> @Idle_Mind That was it!!! I can't believe it was that simple!?! Thanks so much. – J. Canbeno